# Access html of loaded html page in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi assuming I have a main.js and I have the following code:

```
$("#mirador").load("mirador.html");
```

that loads the html in index.html

```
<div id="mirador"></div>
```

Is there any way I can change the innerHTML of mirador.html elements by id from main.js?

I was thinking soemthing along these lines:

```
$("#placeholder").load("b.xhtml #id2", function(){
    var myTemp = document.querySelector("#id2");
    if (myTemp) {
        alert(myTemp.innerHTML);
    } else {
        alert("#id2 is undefined");
    };
});
```

but I don't want to alert but change the content ex:

```
myTemp.innerHTML = "abc";
```

Comment: What did you try and didn't work?

Comment: The code you've written in the question will work when you add it all together. Do you have a specific issue with it?

Answer (score 0):

**Note** : **id** should be unique

```
$("#mirador").load("mirador.html",()=>{

     $("#mirador").find("#id2").html("abc")

});
```

If you have non-unique **id's** use this

```
 $("#mirador").load("mirador.html",()=>{

     $("#mirador").find("#id2").each(function(e){

               $(this).html("abc")
     })

});
```